# How to replace all non-numbers while importing csv to python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I want to import a *dirty* csv file into a numpy object. I have a very few amount of values that are apparently not an `integer` or `float`, because the output is not of the correct dtype.

The code I use:

```
d.data = np.genfromtxt(inputtable, delimiter=";",skip_header=2, comments="@", dtype=np.float)
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to just replace all non floats into -1 so that I do not need to find these values by hand in the `10.000+` rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a provide a set of callbacks as the `converters` argument, as [documented here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

> converters : variable, optional
>
> The set of functions that convert the data of a column to a value. The converters can also be used to provide a default value for missing
>   data: converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)}.

Comment: @BasvanStein glad I could help - and feel free to accept my answer then ;)

Comment: I wanted to but I had to wait 1 minute haha :)